# Write XLSX file to external storage in Android

Tags: java, android, file, xlsx

I'm trying to create and save an XLSX file into my **Download** folder, but even if it doesn't gives error, nothing gets saved. This is the code:

```
private void importIntoExcel() throws IOException {
    String[] columns = { "Numero Test", "Genere", "Data di nascita", "Data del test"};

    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("RiepilogoTest");

    Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();
    headerFont.setBold(true);
    headerFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 14);
    headerFont.setColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());

    CellStyle headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    headerCellStyle.setFont(headerFont);

    // Create a Row
    Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(i);
        cell.setCellValue(columns[i]);
        cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
    }

    // Create Other rows and cells with contacts data
    int rowNum = 1;

    // Write the output to a file
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"risultatiTest.xlsx"));
    workbook.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
}
```

Comment: Does `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"risultatiTest.xlsx"` end up with a slash between the filename and the path?

Comment: Have you tried to `close()` the `workbook`, too?